# Opposite command for "ulimit -c unlimited"

Tags: eclipse, ulimit, jvm

I encountered a bug in eclipse with [this](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/127859651/hs_err_pid29885.log) error log reported as [Bug #1097078](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1097078). According to the error log, there was a line as

```
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Then, I executed `ulimit -c unlimited`.

Now I think (not sure) it is causing some problem as my eclipse is closing automatically which showed some error message like (not accurate) `memory full, you don't have enough memory to collect data` the first time.

My question is, what is the command opposite to `ulimit -c unlimited`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable core dumps by setting the core limit to 0:

`ulimit -c 0`

This is the default setting, so it has no effect unless you've previously run another `ulimit -c` command.